# What do you call a room in a company where you can learn the company's products by practice?

Tags: single-word-requests

This room provides all the company's products (assuming this company is an electronic device manufacturer) and a newcomer can learn how these devices work and how to operate them by operating them him/her-self?

*Training room* is not an option. Because there is already a training room where you can learn theories.

Comment: Training room is not an option. Because there is already a training room where you can learn theories.

Comment: Demonstration room, or demo room. You can replace "room" with "space" or "area." (I could imagine Willy Wonka calling such a room a "playroom," "play pit," or "play pen.")

Comment: Test room maybe?

Comment: @user2768 - Your suggestions made me think about [**sandbox**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sandbox?s=ts). It's not quite right as it apparently means a virtual environment rather than a real one, but thought I'd mention it in case it sparks off someone else's brain.

Comment: 'Product Demonstration Room' would be my choice. Just 'Demonstration' room could be demonstrating anything - sales techniques, first aid etc etc.

Comment: *Practice room* or *learning lab*. Sorry: *Your* problem is the false distinction against *training room where you can learn theories*. A training room is where one learns or teaches whatever is needed.

A *demo* room would be where an expert gave a broad explanation, not by any means somewhere one could *learn… by practice*.

A *test* room would be where one tried to find things out for himself; yes,  somewhere one could *learn… by practice* but not at all as you seem to mean.

Broadly, most corporations cal that a *training room*.

Comment: @AndyT I think *sandbox* works well in this context. It carries the notion that people can safely try things out, without worrying that they might interfere with their customers' use of the products.

Comment: what type of company? example: a drone company could have the 'hanger'.

Answer (score -1):

You could call it a "demo-room" demo being shorthand for demonstration.

Comment: Sorry, Neil and no, you could not. Sherman clearly explained he was asking about how a newcomer can learn how these devices work and how to operate them *by operating them him/her-self*?

A *demo-room* - shorthand for *demonstration* - is where an expert shows the newbies what's what; not where they find out for themselves.